# How to make a local folder to be a git repository (already existed on remote)

Tags: git

I have a git repository on remote server called `test`, with files `hello.py` and `test.py`.

And I have a local folder called `workspace` with file named `goodbye.py`.
Can I make the local folder `workspace` to be the repository(`test`)  directly?

I mean under `workspace`, there are `hello.py` and `test.py` and `goodbye.py`.

I want to ask this because if there are 3 members, they write code separately in their folders, and now we have to use git to control, so how to make the local folder to clone git repository directly?

Comment: Check this answer to see if it solves your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1425892/how-do-you-merge-two-git-repositories

Answer (score 1):

You can clone the repository with *git clone* to an empty directory, and then add your local files manually.

Answer (score 1):

From your `workspace` folder, you can do the following:

1. `git init`
2. `git add goodbye.py`
3. `git commit -m "Initial commit on my local machine"`
4. `git remote add origin <path-to-remote-git-repository>`
5. `git pull origin master`

This last one will `fetch` the data from the remote location and `merge` the remote `master`branch (i.e. `origin/master`) with your local `master` branch. I recommend you to search in the documentation for any of these commands if you are not sure of what they do before trying anything.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a tool like [SmartGit](http://www.syntevo.com/smartgit/), which gives you an interface to work with. Or you can do it with the terminal (which I recommand). Check out that quick tutorial! [Getting an existing git repository](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Getting-a-Git-Repository)